# What is $\mathbb{F}_q((1/T))/\mathbb{F}_q[T]$ as a topological space?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

We fix a prime power $q$, and we let $\mathbb{F}_q((1/T))$ be the completion of $\mathbb{F}_q[T]$ at infinity. We have the absolute value on $\mathbb{F}_q((1/T))$,
$$\bigg{|}\sum_{i=-\infty}^n a_iT^i \bigg{|} = n $$
if $a_n \neq 0$. Now we can define a metric on $\mathbb{T} := \mathbb{F}_q((1/T))/\mathbb{F}_q[T]$ as
$$||f|| = \inf_{f' \sim f}|f'| $$
where $\sim$ is the usual relation from the quotient.

I am wondering if $\mathbb{T}$ is homeomorphic to a well known topological space? I know that this is quite analogous to $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, which is homeomorphic to a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $$\mathbb{F}_q((T^{-1})) =T^{-1} \mathbb{F}_q[[T^{-1}]] \oplus \Bbb{F}_q[T]$$
This is a direct sum of topological groups, each term in the RHS inherits a metric from the LHS.

Note that $\mathbb{F}_p[[T^{-1}]]$ is homeomorphic to the $p$-adic integers $\Bbb{Z}_p$, the map is $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n T^{-n} \to \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n p^n$ for $a_n\in 0\ldots p-1$.

They are homemorphic to a subset of (the topological space) $\Bbb{R}$, the map is $\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n T^{-n}\to \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n p^{-2n}$.

A $\Bbb{F}_p$ basis of $\mathbb{F}_q$ makes $\mathbb{F}_q[[T^{-1}]]$ a rank $[\Bbb{F}_q:\Bbb{F}_p]$ free $\mathbb{F}_p[[T^{-1}]]$ module.